# Catch html5 geolocation events

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

Is there a way to catch the html5 geolocation events?

Right now im using geolocator.js

and my problem is:

When the message pops up if i want to allow html5 locations if i accept it takes html5 location if I get ipLocation.

But I want to listen for these clicks so I can set a timeout if the user doesn't click for 10 seconds it automatically takes ip location.

Is there any way to get the event for "accept" and "decline"? Here is my code snippet for it

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoError, html5Options);
    } else { // not supported
        fallback(new Error('geolocation is not supported.'));
    }
```

EDIT: Im using Chrome on iMac

EDIT 2:

```
var html5Options = { enableHighAccuracy: true,timeout: 10000, maximumAge: 0 };
```

EDIT 3: using the solution by kravitz

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
        waitTooLong=setTimeout(geoError, 15000);
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoError, html5Options);
    } else { // not supported
        fallback(new Error('geolocation is not supported.'));
    }

function geoSuccess(position) {
        clearTimeout(waitTooLong);
       //doing my locationstuff
}

function geoError(error) {
        //doing my locationstuff
        clearTimeout(waitTooLong);
        fallback(error);
 }
```

Comment: So do you want to know when the user has clicked that they "accept" geo-locations, and if they don't click "accept" you just do it anyway?

Comment: No if they use accept I use html5 location. Otherwise I use IPLocation.

Answer (score 1):

```
var geoError = function(){
  //get location failed so get manually by IP here
};

if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoError, html5Options);
    } else { // not supported
        fallback(new Error('geolocation is not supported.'));
    }
```

Above should work but if you want to be really sure:

```
var timeOut = setTimeout(geoError, 10000);
var geoSuccess =  function(){
   clearTimeout(timeOut);
};
```

Comment: Thats what im doing right now but he doesnt use geoError after the timeout.. normally he would take ipLocation after 10 seconds..

Comment: but i guess there is no way to track the clicking / nor close the window with javascript

Comment: Have you tried putting an alert() in start of geoError function to see if it gets there? It would be strange especially from a setTimeout call to not get to the geoError function.

Comment: make sure geoError and geoSuccess are defined before/above using them or the setTimeout

Comment: yes i tried to use console.log in the geoError but it doesnt pop when doing nothing.. If i decline it works perfectly..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5zjwva4a/1/ this should work for you? Can you replicate the problem on jsfiddle?